# SSRS 2008 Expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to write IIF statement in `SSRS 2008` experssions but can run only one part at a time... the other part gives error... here is what am writing..

```
=IIF(Parameters!Month.Value = 1,  " "& CStr(MonthName(Parameters!Month.Value +11)) &" " ,  "ABC")
```

When ever i run this and value of Month parameter = 1 then it runs fine but when `value  <> 1` then it gives `#Error`... The false part is not executing... I think some thing wrong with double quotes...

Even if i change positions of true and false sets...result is same... If i simply write like..

`=IIF(Parameters!Month.Value = 1,  "CDE" ,  "ABC")`

then it all runs fine...

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an assumptive mismatch of metadata.  Even though you are calling out CStr() it could be something on that front.  Trying wrapping the false statement in CStr() as well as dropping the " " & and & " " and see what happens.  That's where I'd start.

Comment: i tried to add CStr in false statement as well and removed all "" &  &""... but same result...

Comment: How about put the Parameters!Month.Value in one field, Parameters!Month.Value +11 in another, CStr(MonthName(Parameters!Month.Value +11)) in another.  I'm curious where the error is actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no issue** with the Quotes.

Months are only between 1 to 12. Based on your equation **Parameters!Month.Value** can only be from **-10 to 1**.

If you supply any value greater than 1 or less than -10 or any decimal values you expression will error out. You need to check all the values you are passing in `Parameters!Month.Value` or change your expression.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it.....

=IIF(Parameters!Month.Value = 1,
MonthName((((Parameters!Month.Value-1)+11) Mod 12 )+ 1) + "-" + CStr(Parameters!Year.Value - 1),
                                  MonthName((((Parameters!Month.Value-1)+11) Mod 12 ) + 1) + " - " + Parameters!Year.Value)